# On the smoothness of plumbed $4$-manifolds and $E_8$ manifold

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 4-manifolds

The $E_8$ manifold can be constructed by plumbing together disk bundles of Euler number $2$ over $2$-sphere $S^2$ according to the Dynkin diagram for $E_8$.

In [Smooth 4-manifolds with $E_8$ intersection form](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193777/smooth-4-manifolds-with-e-8-intersection-form), it is written that an $E_8$ manifold cannot be smoothed by Donaldson's diagonalization theorem. By [Freedman - The topology of four-dimensional manifolds](https://doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214437136), on the other hand, $E_8$ manifold bounds a contractible topological $4$-manifold. So this is a very interesting example for $4$-dimensional topology.

Saveliev (as well as several mathematicians) wrote in the book *[Invariants of Homology 3-Spheres](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-04705-7)* that such a plumbing construction gives rise to a simply connected smooth $4$-manifold.

Where is the problem? Are they just typos, or does pasting disk bundles create "corners" which cannot be smoothed so that the resulting $4$-manifold might not be smooth?

Comment: The plumbing along the $E_8$ graph yields a smooth four-manifold with intersection form $E_8$ that bounds the Poincare homology sphere. Freedman constructed the $E_8$ manifold from this by attaching a compact contractible topological four-manifold that bounds the Poincare homology sphere. Donaldson's theorem essentially implies you can't do this smoothly.

Comment: Poincare homology sphere should be the boundary of $E_8$. I don't follow the part "Freedman's construction". Could you explain it more?

Comment: Donaldson's diagonalization theorem implies any _closed_ smooth four-manifold cannot have intersection form $E_8$. The plumbing only gives a smooth four-manifold with boundary with intersection form $E_8$. However, Freedman showed that any integral homology three-sphere bounds a compact contractible topological four-manifold, so you can cap off the Poincare sphere boundary to get a topological four-manifold with intersection form $E_8$, which is usually what people call the "$E_8$-manifold".

Comment: So, the critical word is "closed", right?

Comment: And the plumbing $4$-manifold with $E_8$ and Freedman's $E_8$ manifold are not same.

Comment: Your link "Freedman" originally pointed to Wikipedia.  I assumed the intended target was his article referenced there, so I edited the link (and added the title of the article).

Comment: Before Donaldson, there was Rokhlin's theorem, that the signature of the intersection form of a smooth closed spin 4-manifold is divisible by 16 (rather than just 8 as the arithmetic implies). This is enough to show that the $E_8$ manifold is not smoothable.